# Specflow: How to configure environment variables

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, specflow

I would like to configure environment variables like connection strings for my specflow tests  in such a way that my tests should use my appsettings locally and use the values from keyvaults/pipeline environment variables while running in pipeline.I would like to achieve this without specifying any AddJsonFile. Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean this: Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("lorem", "ipsum");
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0

Comment: Thanks, this seems more straight forward than I thought. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set EnvironmentVariable:

```cs
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("lorem", "ipsum");
```

[Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0)

> Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored in the current process.